# GitHub tags shown on wrong commit

Tags: git, github

So I have a project with two branches: `master` and `stable`. `master` is where feature and bug branches are split from and merged into. The `master` branch is merged into `stable` for every release. I'm trying to follow [this](https://gist.github.com/digitaljhelms/4287848#workflow-diagram) workflow. So I just released a new version, merged `master` into `stable` and tagged the merge commit. Locally, `git log` looks like this:

[image: local git log]

So the tag `v1.1.0` should appear on commit `31b58ba` right? On GitHub, the release was picked up and looks like this:

[image: GitHub release]

But when I click the commit link under the tag name on the left, I see this:

[image: GitHub commit view]

No tag to be found. Now here's the interesting part (for me at least), when I visit a previous release, tagged v1.0.0, I see this:

[image: GitHub commit view]

Both tags are seen on this commit. I am pretty new to Git tags and GitHub releases so there is a very big chance that I'm misunderstanding something here. One thing I noticed is that the `v1.0.0` tag is on the `master` branch (default branch) while the `v1.1.0` tag is on the `stable` branch. I'm not sure if that could have anything to do with it. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have pushed the update to the tag reference. So github has the merge commit, but did not update the tag location.

Use the same convention as branches:

```
git push origin v1.0.0
```

Tags don't refer to branches, only commit references.

Comment: Would the op also require a force push?

Comment: No success :( One of the confusing parts is that the tag `v1.1.0` was never on commit `71d4da0` (the second commit screenshot), but it shows up there on GitHub. Locally, the tags are where they should be (`v1.1.0` on the merge commit on `stable` and `v1.0.0` on the release commit on `master`), and they have both been pushed.

Comment: What about `git push —tags`?

Comment: That will push ALL tags created locally. Maybe not an issue, but if there are other tags locally (or old ones deleted on the server) they will be pushed too.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I believe that has the same effect in my case. I don't think the issue is that the tags haven't been pushed correctly, they just aren't displayed on the correct commits on GitHub.